# React bootstrap not rendering style

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap

Bootstrap styles not rendering when everything is setup fine. I have install react-bootstrap and imported bootstrap css, but i cannot get the style to render. I can make it work through a create-react-app boilerplate. I suspect that it has something to do with my bootstrap. this is my webpack.config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style?sourceMap',
                    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=25000'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: Something may be screwy with the import of the bootstrap CSS. I added `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to the top of my index.js and that worked. Alternatively, you can add a the link to the bootstrap .css in your index.html as described in https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html.